# React Redux act strangely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

below is my reducer and its output. The result is very weird. 
The variable **actions.pokemons**: is an array with each element is an object. It value is assigned to a and copy to b. 
I dont understand why b is empty array. Also, the return value is an empty array, state not update?

```
const pokemons = (state=[], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case types.FETCH_POKEMON:
            var a = action.pokemons
            console.log(a)
            var b = [...action.pokemons]
            console.log(b)
            return a;

        default: return [...state];
    }
}
```

[image]

This is my action file:

```js
import * as types from '../constants/index';
import axios from 'axios'; 
export const actFetchPokemonsRequest = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        var result = [];
        for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
            axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`,
                data: null
            }).then(res => {
                // console.log(res.data)
                result.push(res.data)
                return dispatch(actFetchPokemon(result))
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
        return dispatch(actFetchPokemon(result))
    }
}

export const actFetchPokemon = pokemons => {
    return {
        type: types.FETCH_POKEMON,
        pokemons
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to check the behavior of the spread operator

Comment: I might have a clue as to what's happening. In the console, when `a` is logged, it's empty until you actually open it up. This is what happens when the result when it's logged is different than when the program is actually run. The action is dispatched with `a`, which is empty, it copies it to `b`, which becomes empty, then something later down the line is adding more items to `a`, which causes the extra items to show up in the devtools when expanded.

Comment: So... make sure the items are there before dispatching?

Comment: can you add one more line console.log(action.pokemons) before assigning to var a or b. That will clear what is going on.

Comment: @kingdaro all are sequential  instructions,how its possible that . u r saying

Comment: @kingdaro i dont really understand your point, i add my action file for clarification

Comment: @SibaprasadMaiti the result is similar to the first scenario. I get an array with 2 objects

Comment: After the update with the action file, you'll probably want to replace the loop with `Promise.all` and map an array of `Promises`. There's a mix of asynchronous and synchronous code.

Comment: the dispatch statement below the for loop is called synchronously... you should wait until all promises resolved and then dispatch the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone already mentioned your asynchronous part does not work as you think it does. Here is what's happening.

1. You instantiate an empty array called result
2. You start a for loop and each loop STARTS a Promise, you reach the end of the for loop **before** any Promise is resolved. The loop ends very fast and your code goes to the next statement.
3. In your return statement you invoke a dispatch passing in an action that receives an array. You get here right after the for loop and since none of the Promises have resolved yet your `result` is empty.

The way to do this is the following:

```
import * as types from '../constants/index';
import axios from 'axios'; 

export const actFetchPokemonsRequest = () => {      
    return dispatch => {
      const pokemonRequests = [
        axios({ method: 'GET', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/0', data: null }),
        axios({ method: 'GET', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1', data: null }),
        axios({ method: 'GET', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2', data: null }),
      ];

      Promise.all(pokemonRequests).then((responses) => {
        const dataArr = responses.map(r => r.data);

        dispatch(actFetchPokemon(dataArr));
      });
    }
}

export const actFetchPokemon = pokemons => {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_POKEMON,
    pokemons,
  }
}
```

In your reduce you would simply have:

```
const pokemons = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case types.FETCH_POKEMON:
      return [...action.pokemons];
      // Or if you want to simply extend what you currently have
      // return [...state, ...action.pokemons];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

To go into more details about the asynch part, what happens is that you fire off all of your `axios` requests. But you want to wait for ALL of them to resolve, this is where `Promise.all` comes in handy. Promise.all waits for all of the Promises to resolve and then concatenates into an array the response (if any) of each promise. This is way I can use `.map` on it and actually extract the `data` field from each request response. Once I am done with all of this I can finally dispatch my action now passing a valid array of data. There's plenty of documentation about `Promise.all` so I would recommend giving it a look.

I hope this helps with your problem, let me know if this doesn't work out for you.

NOTE: for simplicity sake I manually wrote down all the requests but there's many better ways to do that dynamically.